# Paypal button not showing

Tags: image, paypal, https, paypal-sandbox, content-security-policy

Since this morning, I am getting a weird issue with the paypal button.

It shows for 1 seconds when I navigate to it, then it appears broken and I see the following message in the console:

> www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/button?env=sandbox&style.size=small&s…l&style.label=pay&version=4&uid=154887c448&locale.x=en_US&xcomponent=1:452 Refused to load the image 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjMyIiB2aWV3Qm94P…E3IEMgOTUuNCA0LjkxNyA5NS4yIDUuMTE3IDk1LjEgNS40MTcgWiI+PC9wYXRoPgo8L3N2Zz4K' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src https:".

Did anything change ?

Comment: i see this error to

Comment: Me too since this morning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Paypal sorted the issue on their own.
The error is gone and the button shows properly.